# CSRF Codeigniter protection and AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf-protection

I have to ask help to solve an issue with AJX call in Codeigniter.
I have CSRF protection on in my system and usually it works fine even with AJAX/jQuery call.
Now I got in trouble with the following code and I'm not able to fix it...just got a great headache
What I'm trying to do is call a controller every time a checkbox state is changed (I'm using Switchery ); I'd like to get the switch working correctly several times...not just at the first switch.
The javascript code is the following:

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
   var csrfName = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>';
   var csrfHash = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';
   var changeCheckbox = document.querySelector('.js-switch'), changeField = document.querySelector('#results');

   changeCheckbox.onchange = function() {
      changeField.innerHTML = changeCheckbox.checked;
       $.ajax({
           url: 'myphpfile',
           type: 'POST',        
           data : {
               csrfName: csrfHash,
               "checked": changeCheckbox.checked
           }, 
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(result){
               $("#results").append(result.error);
               csrfName = result.csrfHash;
           }
       });
   };

   });
```

The script above doesn't work even at first attempt and I get an 403 error ( forbidden ) so, the csrf hash is not passed at all....this is really weird because if I set ( using the PHP echo code ) the csrf name and csrf hash directly into the S.ajax data brackets, the script works fine...even if just once.
So the questions are: why the csrfName and csrfHash variables are not passed along the data? How can I make the AJAX csrf working fine several times?
Sorry for my bad english, hope I explained my issues
Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you mean is:

```
var data = {"checked": changeCheckbox.checked};
    data[csrfName] = csrfHash;
```

and then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myphpfile',
    type: 'POST',        
    data : data
[...]
```

`csrfName` is a variable, so if you want to add a property named with the contents of `csrfName` you have to use object[variable] syntax. 
By writing:

```
data : {
    csrfName: csrfHash
}
```

you are creating an object with `csrfName` property, not its contents.

Or if you're using ES6, you can write:

```
data : {
    [csrfName]: csrfHash,
    "checked": changeCheckbox.checked
}
```

Comment: also note `document.querySelector` only returns first matching element...not all matches

Comment: Thanks a lot for feedback and comments. Adam, yout hint solved the issue; now the script works fine at the first checkbox switch. Should I edit the csrfName = result.csrfHash; row in success function to make it working more then once?

Comment: Just to add more info...I checked the JSON code return by the PHP script and it provide correctly the new hash for the next POST submit:`
csrfHash
:
"18911515b6521496f1dfcfa88bc5da6d"
csrfName
:
"csrf_ats_name"`

Comment: @Federico yes it should work, if not, declare the variable out of the scope of on ready function

Comment: Negative :( ...I cannot call AJAX more then once . I moved the var csrfHash and var csrfName outside ready function...but I cannot get the new hash for next AJAX call...still getting 403 error from server. I really have no idea how to fix that...

Comment: @Federico note, that you get csrfHash and csrfName, what you do: `csrfName = result.csrfHash;` does not make any sense, since you're asigning a csrfHash to a csrfName. In order to make it work, you have to replace both.

Comment: Something like: `csrfName = result.csrfName; csrfHash = result.csrfHash;`

Comment: Silly me.....I have to learn a lot about Js. Thanks a lot Adam...fixed and working fine thanks to your invaluable help

Comment: @Federico if your issue is resolved, please accept the answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are making an ajax call more the one time all you need to do just user jquery.cookie method to send csrfhash and csrfcookie values.here you can download jquery.cookie  https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
and pass values of csrf via ajax like this .

```
"data:<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>": Cookies.get('csrf_cookie_name')
```

just change the csrf_cookie_name according to you cookie name and it's done.i hope  will help you